# Fixed position header is giving trouble while scrolling the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am working on one responsive design and i have used bootstrap framework with fixed position header. I am facing one problem in mobile view, as the position of the second level horizontal menu is fixed, while scrolling the page, the banner part gets hidden, when we scroll the page from top to bottom and again from bottom to top. The banner part is not visible. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Please share your code... Just the code...

Comment: Which mobile OS & browser & versions? Which Bootstrap version?